# Player class winning percentage java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method for " winning percentage " in a player class. I know I need to incorporate total wins divided by total games played, but the code is meant to be simple so I cannot use complex code. (beginner project in computer science) Any useful feedback would be great as I have spent multiple days attempting this and getting no where. By the way, ties count as half a win.

**Update: Implemented the getters into the getWinningPercentage method. Also calculated everything inside the getWinningPercentage and removed the setWinningPercentage considering it was useless code. Results were as follows: 
Bob
5 wins, 1 losses, 2 ties
Winning percentage = 0.75**

```
public class Player
{
    private int numWins = 0;
    private int numTies = 0;
    private int numLosses = 0;
    private String name;

    public void setWins(int w)
    {
        numWins = w;
    }
    public int getWins()
    {
        return numWins;
    }
    public void setTies(int t)
    {
        numTies = t;
    }
    public int getTies()
    {
        return numTies;
    }
    public void setLosses(int L)
    {
        numLosses = L;
    }
    public int getLosses()
    {
        return numLosses;
    }
    public void setName(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void incrementWins()
    }
        numWins++;
    }
    public void incrementTies()
    {
        numTies++;
    }
    public void incrementLosses()
    {
        numLosses++;
    }
    public double getWinningPercentage()
    {
        double totalGames = getWins() + getTies() + getLosses();
        double totalWins = getWins() + (getTies() / 2.0);
        double winningPercentage = (totalWins / totalGames);

        return winningPercentage;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. I don't think that you should have a `setWinningPercentage`, unless that has been specifically required. Instead your `getWinningPercentage()` should be a calculated property where you calculate and return the actual winning percentage at that point in time.

Comment: You described what you are trying to do but didn't say anything about what specific problem you faced when doing it.

Comment: Then do it -- create a `getWinningPercentage()`, do your calculations of this percentage in the method, and return the value from the method. Get rid of the `setter` method.

Comment: The issue is how do I create a method to return the winning percentage given the information " total wins divided by number of games played ". also, I do not know how to incorporate number of games played or total wins into the code.

Comment: That's primary school math -- try to do it and see what you can come up with. Show your attempt please with this and with all questions.

Comment: Side note - in your setWinningPercentage you ask for a parameter of total games to be given, but then you instantly discard that and calculate it on your own anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The winning percentage should be a calculated property, not a field, and not have a setter method. Instead there should only be a "getter" (`public double getWinningPercentage()`) method and you should calculate and return this value from within the method itself from the other fields that your class already has.

We should leave it up to you to create this method and formula yourself.

Comment: You were right. Although you were a bit cold, I still considered your advice and it worked out. Updating the code now.